# Javascript REGEX - EXACT TEXT AND DIGIT

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regex that exactly match the text 'PDR' or 'pdr' and 8 digit so altogether 11 digit ,( 3 text + 8 digit)

> pdr16120008 - TRUE
>
> PDR16120009 -TRUE
>
> rdp16120001- FALSE

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. We are not an e-lancing site

Answer (score 0):

### [Regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/yh0n8A/1)

```
^(pdr|PDR)\d{8}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/pWLNeECiDUmfg2i0)

### Description

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
1st Capturing Group (pdr|PDR)
    1st Alternative pdr
        pdr matches the characters pdr literally (case sensitive)
    2nd Alternative PDR
        PDR matches the characters PDR literally (case sensitive)
\d{8} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
    {8} Quantifier — Matches exactly 8 times
$ asserts position at the end of a line
```

Comment: So despite my comment we just give in to "gimme the codez" ;)

Comment: @mplungjan it is regex, people struggle to comprehend it at all.  The description will hopefully get him and others googling this closer to understanding.  also i didn't see your comment until you wrote it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The regex isn't difficult:

1. match `pdr` litterally at the start using `^` anchor
2. match exactly **8** `digits` using a character class and a quantifier
3. use the `i` modifier in order to match as case insensitive.

```js
const REGEX = /^pdr[0-9]{8}$/i;

let valids = ['pdr16120008', 'PDR16120009', 'rdp16120001']
  .filter(input => REGEX.test(input))
;

console.log({valids});
```

Comment: This would also match `PdR` or any other combo since it is case insensitive